# What defines an opaque type in C, and when are they necessary and/or useful?

Tags: c, types

I've seen the concept of 'opaque types' thrown around a bit but I really haven't found a succinct answer as to what defines an opaque type in C and more importantly what problems they allow us to solve with their existence.  Thanks

Comment: `FILE` is a good example of an opaque type in the C standard.  All you ever need is a `FILE *` object, and use standard C functions that operate on it.  You as a programmer don't care what the `FILE` type consists of.

Comment: `pthread_t` is an opaque type

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It is the most generally used for library purpose. The main principe behind Opaque type in c is to use data though its pointer in order to hide data handling implementation. Since the implementation is hidden, you can modify the library without recompiling any program which depend on it (if the interface is respected)

eg:
version 1:

```
// header file
struct s;

int s_init(struct s **x);
int s_f(struct s *x);
int s_g(struct s *x);

// source file
struct s { int x; }

int s_init(struct s **x) { *x = malloc(...); }
int s_f(..) { ... }
int s_g(..) { ... }
```

version 2

```
// header file
struct s;

int s_init(struct s **x);
int s_f(struct s *x);
int s_g(struct s *x);

// source file
struct s { int y; int x; }

int s_init(struct s **x) { *x = malloc(...); }
int s_f(..) { ... }
int s_g(..) { ... }
```

From your program side, nothing changed! and as said previously, no need to recompile every single program which rely on it.

Comment: I am assuming that the '//implementation' portions are not apart of the same '//header file' and are what go in the libraries? Also, it seems like you declared `struct s` in the header but never defined it until the implementation.  I recently read a great post on `extern` variables in C http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c  The concepts seem strikingly similar, should not `struct s` be declared as `extern struct s` in your sample code?

Comment: using extern for variable is generally used to declare global variable (which is absolutely not related to our case). Here the instruction struct s; is here to indicate to the compilator a type named struct s exist. Since all API in the header file ONLY use pointer to this strucure. It does not need to know the structure size but the size of the pointer of structure (which is define by the compiler). To simplify, it allows the program use a object by using its address (the pointer to the structure)

Comment: siegeX: I changed the post to avoid the confusion about implementation

Comment: @SiegeX There exists no case in C where you need to declare a non-const variable as `extern`. Apart from the case where you have global constants, the extern keyword is only good for spaghetti programming. If you ever find yourself declaring variables as extern/global, it is a certain sign that your program design is very bad.

Answer (score 25):

In my understanding, opaque types are those which allow you to hold a handle (i.e., a pointer) to an structure, but not modify or view its contents directly (if you are allowed to at all, you do so through helper functions which understand the internal structure).

Opaque types are, in part, a way to make C more object-oriented. They allow encapsulation, so that the internal details of a type can change--or be implemented differently in different platforms/situations--without the code that uses it having to change.

Comment: Quibble: this idiom is *only* about encapsulation. Encapsulation is necessary to object-orientation, but it is the smallest piece of it.

Comment: True, it takes a lot more than this for anything nearly object-oriented. Still, it is the one part of object-oriented design that I find I am *always* missing when I write in C. Plus, if you *were* to try to emulate inheritance and polymorphism in C (more work than it is worth), you would almost certainly need to start with opaque types.

Comment: Remember that c and the culture that it engendered date from a time when object orientation was a rare and still rather experimental thing. Procedural and functional programmers of the time concentrated of encapsulation as *the* means of controlling inter-connectivity and unnecessary complexity. Talking about opaque types in c as a kind of crippled object is pushing a foreign POV onto the language. – dmckee 10 mins ago

Comment: @dmckee It is not only for encapsulation. You can use opaque type to implement inheritance/polymorphism as well, even if that was perhaps not the original intention of incomplete type. Anyway, most importantly object orientation is a program _design method_, it is _not_ a language feature. No matter language you should always use an object-oriented program design! And after the design is done, you can have a look at what language features that are available and check how you best implement your design in the specific language.

Answer (score 15):

An opaque type is a type which is exposed in APIs via a pointer but never concretely defined.