# No-copy type annotation

Tags: c, opaque-pointers

In C, if a structure contains a futex or for whatever reason doesn't make sense to copy or move to a new address, is there any way (type annotation or something) to restrict/warn users from accidentally making copies of those objects?

Comment: Making the type [opaque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301454/what-defines-an-opaque-type-in-c-and-when-are-they-necessary-and-or-useful) should prevent most such things.

Comment: There is nothing in the C standard related to making a type or variable uncopyable.  There may be non-standard extensions in some compilers.  If there are such extensions, it's likely that other compilers do it differently.  You're moving into the realm of non-portable code, which may or may not matter to you.

Answer (score 1):

You do could do something similar with opaque type and private encapsulation.

**something.h**

```
typedef struct something something; // forward declaration, incomplete/opaque type

something* something_create  (void);
void       something_dostuff (something* obj);
```

**something.c**

```
#include "something.h"

struct something { ... }; // actual definition, only visible privately in this file

something* something_create  (void)
{
  something* result = malloc( sizeof *result );
  ...
  return result;
}

void something_dostuff (something* obj)
{
  /* do stuff on the object */
}
```

**caller.c**

```
#include "something.h"

something* st = something_create();
something_dostuff(st);
```

Now of course this doesn't stop the caller from doing dirty hacks on purpose such as wild `memcpy` on the pointed-at data. But is stops a sane application programmer from doing things by mistake, which ought to be the aim of this.

Answer (score -1):

No, there are not. Looks you picked the wrong language, try Rust, Go, Java, Python etc. Though I guess some (or all) of them doesn't support this feature too but it's the right direction.

As the comment points out, if it is not desirable to let user copy the structure, just always use pointers.

If it would be problem giving the structure intels to the user, it is possible to substitute the structure members with same-size nonsenses in the header file for the user, and reserve the real header file yourself, like how WinAPI does. However, this would make everything complicated since the type size, structure alignment etc. are different sometimes in different architectures.

Comment: You could have mentioned C++ which is closer to C and does support non copiable types.

Comment: "Try other languages that doesn't support the feature either" doesn't seem like a useful answer to me. Except you _can_ do something like this in every language I can think of except maybe assembler. " it is possible to substitute the structure members with same-size nonsenses in the header file for the user"  No, that's not how you do private encapsulation in C. You don't expose the struct definition in the first place.